# Rdlc Report - Footer only on first page

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, rdlc

I have an .rdlc report written and working in a Visual Studio 2013 report viewer. It contains several subreports which are shown or hidden under certain conditions. It has a footer that shows on just the first page. I can print multiple pages exactly how I want: footer on first page, with no footer on the remaining pages.

My problem is when the report is generated as a single page. If the report is one page, there is no footer at all. But, I still need that footer to show.

My footer properties are set to:

```
Show footer for this page = True
Print on first page = True  
Print on last page = False
```

It seems that the last page being false overrides the first page being true. Since a one-page report is both a first and last page, no footer shows. It seems like a simple fix, but I've seen no topics about this anywhere.

Any ideas or workarounds? Thanks for you help!